# Are discussion oriented questions authorized?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question

I read this question:

https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/21161/cliche-world-who-would-you-be-and-why

And I wondered if it were okay. Can we authorize questions which lead to discussions?

Comment: That question is about to be closed as off-topic.